# Sum of products of all pairs in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I want to sum the products of all distinct pairs in a list.  I wrote the following code that counts correctly this: `1*2 + 1*3 + 1*4 + 2*3 + 2*4 + 3*4`

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
def sum_of_pairs(ls):
    return sum([x * y for x in ls for y in ls[ls.index(x) + 1:]])
print(sum_of_pairs(l))
```

When I try to change list to `l = [1, 1, 1, 1]` it returns 12 (and not 6).

Why is this happening?

Comment: How is either 11 or 12 the correct answer? Why aren't you expecting 6?

Comment: Really sorry, expecting 6. My mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate issue is that you are using `ls.index` to find where to start the inner loop. [`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) returns the index of the *first* matching item, so will only do what you want if there are no duplicates in the list. Another problem is that it performs a linear search of your list for every iteration of the outer loop, making your algorithm needlessly inefficient.

A number of workarounds are available. A simple one is using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to follow along with the index that you want:

```
sum(n * ls[j] for i, n in enumerate(ls) for j in range(i + 1, len(ls)))
```

Or you could use a pair of [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) objects:

```
sum(ls[i] * ls[j] for i in range(len(ls)) for j in range(i + 1, len(ls)))
```

Creating a `range` is generally cheaper than copying out the entire sublist every time, as with

```
 sum(x * y for i, x in enumerate(ls) for y in ls[i + 1:])
```

Alternatively, you could use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to generate the values for you a bit more efficiently:

```
sum(x * y for x, y in itertools.combinations(ls, 2))
```

Comment: May I ask you a last question? Why dont you enclose the whole senteces in [ ] ?

Comment: @KoZark. I was actually going to address that. When you do `[... for ...]`, that's a list comprehension, which makes an actual list. `(...  for ...)` creates a generator expression, which isn't evaluated until you actually iterate it. You can drop the parens, as I did in `sum`. It's cheaper since I don't create the list, just add up the elements.

Answer (score 2):

Instead, use the following short approach with `itertools.starmap` and `itertools.combinations` features:

```
from itertools import starmap, combinations
from operator import mul

def sum_of_pairs(lst):
    return sum(starmap(mul, combinations(lst, 2)))

print(sum_of_pairs([1, 2, 3, 4]))   # 35
print(sum_of_pairs([1, 1, 1, 1]))   # 6
```

Comment: Good use of builtins.